# Automatically unlock iPad mini 5 upon pickup

Tags: ipad

I have a recently released iPad mini 5. Is there anyway I can automatically have my iPad unlock when I pick it up, so its ready to use straight away?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the recent crop of iPhone and iPad Pro, iPad mini 5 doesn't feature Face ID. It comes with a physical Home button with a Touch ID built-in. Neither does it feature Raise to Wake setting, which automatically wakes the screen when you pick up the device.

So there's no way you can configure it to unlock without a physical intervention required from your end.

The best/fastest you can do it to configure it to unlock just by resting your finger on the Home button. Go to Settings → General → Accessibility → Home Button and enable Rest Finger to Open.

[image]

This way, you can speed up the process of unlocking your iPad and making it ready for use. Once the setting is enabled:

- If your iPad screen is turned off, simply pressing the Home button will both wake and unlock it.
- If your iPad screen is awake, just resting the finger will unlock it and get it ready to use.

The aforementioned (picking up the iPad, while keeping your registered finger, generally thumb, on the Home button) is the fastest you can go from picking up your iPad to taking it to the unlocked usable state.

Additionally, with the screen awake, you can swipe left to launch the Camera app. The iPad mini 5 also works with Apple Pencil 1st generation. Thus, tapping on the screen with the Apple Pencil will directly launch the Notes app with a new note.

Comment: I think that disabling passcode (and TouchId) would be faster - e.g. any push of the Home button will make it ready to use, even w/o the lag of waiting for the fingerprint sensor

Comment: @ernie Although there would be a minimal difference in time lag, having Touch ID enabled also will provide security by curtaining unintended access to the device. As mentioned in the question, OP is looking for a faster method to "unlock", most likely meaning he/she wish to keep the device locked.

Comment: I have touch id  OFF, it takes several presses of the home button before it unlocks - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Cheetah If you have turned off Touch ID/Passcode to unlock your iPad, you'll require two presses of Home button to get your iPad to usable state (considering the screen is not sleeping), first to wake up the screen, second to come to Home screen. On the other hand, if you have Touch ID enabled, the same can be accomplished with just a single press of Home button, alongwith the added benefit of having your iPad passcode protected and locked.